# Xcode CUI Catalog bug

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I am building a game in Xcode 10.0, using SpriteKit, and currently I don't have an AppIcon in my game. Everything works great.

When I add an icon, some assets "go missing".

What happens is in the console I get the message:

> "CUICatalog: Invalid Request: requesting subtype without specifying idiom for asset named: "img_xxxxx""

And then these images appear with the white box and red cross, just as if they were missing.

Not all images go missing. The ones that go missing specifically are ones inside a .spriteatlas folder I have.

I've tried deleting this folder and putting it back in, doesn't work.

When I remove the icon and build again, the images reappear.

I've searched this bug along the web and to most people it's just a log issue, and their images still show up, but to me it's really annoying because these images stop showing up.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone in the future:
- Remove and re-add an 'AppIcon' in the Assets.xcassets folder.

For some reason this will reset something in xcode and have your assets load again.

Experienced the same issue and this fixed it.